# How to create a precision-recall curve in R from binary data?

Tags: r

I'd like to calculate precision and recall and create a precision-recall plot in R from a binary dataset (did an event occur/not occur). My data is set out similar to the below example.

```r
truth <- rbinom(200, 1, 0.9)
pred_1 <- rbinom(200, 1, 0.8)
pred_2 <- rbinom(200, 1, 0.7)

dat <- data.frame(truth, pred_1, pred_2)

head(dat)
#>   truth pred_1 pred_2
#> 1     1      1      1
#> 2     1      1      1
#> 3     1      1      0
#> 4     0      1      1
#> 5     1      0      1
#> 6     1      1      1
```

I essentially aim to assess the precision and recall of `pred_1` and `pred_2` to determine an "event" (identified as 1) compared to `truth` (criterion). I know there are some packages/functions in R that can visualise precision/recall, but I'm not sure of the best approach for this example. I came across the `pr_curve` function from the `yardstick` package, but I'm not sure how to apply the [example](https://yardstick.tidymodels.org/reference/pr_curve.html) from the documentation to my own dataset. Any pointers as to how I can tackle this will be very helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
library(yardstick)
truth <- rbinom(200, 1, 0.9)
pred_1 <- rbinom(200, 1, 0.8)
pred_2 <- rbinom(200, 1, 0.7)

dat <- data.frame(truth = as.factor(truth), pred_1 = as.numeric(pred_1), pred_2 = as.numeric(pred_2))

autoplot(pr_curve(dat, truth, pred_1))
```

Output:

[image]